# Cannot handle modal alert window after data re-post (using Selenium webdriver C# and IE)

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to pass modal alert window after data re-post using Selenium WebDriver (selenium-dotnet-2.25.1) + IEDriverServer.exe (IEDriverServer_Win32_2.25.2).

This is my test C# code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new OpenQA.Selenium.IE.InternetExplorerDriver();

        // Navigating to gmail.com and submitting wrong data
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("gmail.com");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("Email")).SendKeys("testuser");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("signIn")).Click();
        Thread.Sleep(8000);

        // making the data re-post by F5
        driver.Navigate().Refresh();

        // Handling the aller and accepting it
        IAlert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
        Console.WriteLine(alert.Text);
        alert.Accept();
    }
```

This is program output:

```
    Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
    2.25.2.0
    Listening on port 2783
    To display the webpage again, Internet Explorer needs to
    resend the information you've previously submitted.

    If you were making a purchase, you should click Cancel to
    avoid a duplicate transaction. Otherwise, click Retry to display
    the webpage again.
    Press any key to continue . . .
```

As result, the Alert window disappears without any data re-post and IE shows 'page has been expired'.

Please advice.

Comment: The issue may lie in the fact that instead of "OK" and "Cancel" buttons displaying on the Alert, it's "Retry" and "Cancel".  You may be able to get around this issue by using alert.SendKeys() and sending either an 'ALT+R' or 'SPACEBAR' command.

Answer (score 0):

An "Alert" is defined in Selenium WebDriver as one thing, and one thing only: a dialog box brought to display via JavaScript. That is, the Alert API can only be reliably used for dialogs created by the JavaScript `alert()`, `confirm()`, or `prompt()` functions. For any other dialog, you might get lucky, but the API is not designed to work on those dialogs.